# Network error 2310 with PERMCOPY

Tags: powershell-3.0

```
PERMCOPY \\127.0.0.1 D:\file \\127.0.0.1 E:\file
```

it keep come out

```
Network error 2310
```

I can't google any doc about this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently

> 2310  This shared resource does not exist.

See [Network Management Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for all error codes.

Comment: Could be access denied https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx